# Which one should I use? decimal.Add() or "+"

Tags: c#, .net

I have a question that I can not find the answer.
Imagine that I have two decimal numbers.
When I want to sum the numbers which one and why should I use?

option1:

```
var num1 = 10.456m;
var num2 = 12.033m;

var result = decimal.Add(num1, num2);
```

option2:

```
var num1 = 10.456m;
var num2 = 12.033m;

var result = num1 + num2;
```

Comment: You can use the one that you can read easier.

Comment: Prefer the + operator or your code may end on the daily wtf.

Comment: They will yield the same result, so you can use as you wish.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They are absolutely the same. The `Decimal` class has overloaded the `+` operator calling the same method. So you should use the one that you feel more readable. Personally I prefer the second approach.

`+` operator (courtesy of reflector):

```
[SecuritySafeCritical, __DynamicallyInvokable]
public static decimal operator +(decimal d1, decimal d2)
{
    FCallAddSub(ref d1, ref d2, 0);
    return d1;
}
```

and the Add method:

```
[SecuritySafeCritical, __DynamicallyInvokable]
public static decimal Add(decimal d1, decimal d2)
{
    FCallAddSub(ref d1, ref d2, 0);
    return d1;
}
```

Strict equivalence in terms of IL and performance.

Answer (score 0):

Both c# gives you multiple ways to solve problems you choose the one you find more comfortable. I personally use num1 + num2.

Answer (score 0):

They are both exactly the same, only different in looks.